# Kendo TabStrip: Passing the Parent Model to the ChildAction in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo UI Tab Strip in MVC 4 defined:

```
@model SearchUserModel

@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
  .Name("tabMain")
  .Items(items =>
      {
          items.Add()
               .Text("Search")
               .Content(Html.Action("Form","SearchUser").ToString()).Selected(true);
          items.Add()
               .Text("Manage User")
               .Action("Index", "ManageUser");

      })
  .Animation(false)
  )
```

The ChildAction "Form" is on the **same** Controller "SearchUser" as this parent.

**Question:** How do I pass the parent's **SearchUserModel** to the "Form"/"SearchUser" **ChildAction**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pass the model using the routeValues parameter of the Html.Action() helper like this:

```
Html.Action("Form", "SearchUser", new { model = Model })
```

Then you just need to modify your controller action to accept the model as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult Form (SearchUserModel model)
{
}
```